# ArgumentError in AttendancesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for ask but i've have like 40 hours with this problem, (I´m a newbie) I've reviewed similar questions related to this error but haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a Branch model who has Employees, those Employees have Attendances so when I want to save attendances to Employees I got this error:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/refaccionariasdelvalle/rails-error.png

**Error Code**

```
ArgumentError in AttendancesController#create
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)


Extracted source (around line #82):
 80
 81
 82 def attendance_params(my_params)
 83  my_params.permit(:present, :employee_id)
 84 end
 85
```

**My Controller:**

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 load_and_authorize_resource 
 before_action :set_and_authorize_branch, except: :index_employees
 layout :user_profile_layout 

def show
 @attendances = Attendance.joins(:employee).where(date: params[:date], employee_id: @branch.employees.ids).order('first_name')
 @date = Date.parse(params[:date])
end

def index_employees
 @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
 @attendances = @employee.attendances
 @events = []
 @attendances.each do |attendance|
  event = {}
  event[:title] = attendance.present.to_s
  event[:start] = attendance.date.to_s
  event[:rendering] = "background"
  attendance.present ? event[:backgroundColor] = "#9EB25D" : 
  event[:backgroundColor] = "#CC4B4B"
  @events << event
 end
end

def new
 redirect_to attendance_branch_path(id: @branch, date: Date.today) if !Attendance.where(date: Date.today, employee_id: @branch.employees.ids).empty?
 @attendances = []
 @branch.employees.each do |employee|
  @attendances << Attendance.new(employee_id: employee.id)
 end
 @attendances = @attendances.sort_by { |att| att.employee.first_name }
end

def create
 params[:attendances].each do |attendance|
  new_attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params(attendance))
  new_attendance.date = Date.today
  new_attendance.save
 end
redirect_to branch_class_path(@branch), notice: 'Attendance taken 
successfully'
end

def edit
 @attendances = Attendance.joins(:employee).where(date: params[:date], 
 employee_id: @branch.employees.ids).order('first_name')
 @date = Date.parse(params[:date])
end

def update
 params[:attendances].each do |id, params|
  attendance = Attendance.find(id)
  attendance.update(attendance_params(params))
 end
redirect_to attendance_branch_path(id: @branch, date: params[:date])
end

private

def user_profile_layout
 if  user_signed_in?  && current_user.role.name === "Branch"
  "layout_for_user_branch"
 #elsif  user_signed_in?  && current_user.role.name === "Admin"
 else  
  "application_for_user_admin"  
 end
end

def set_and_authorize_branch
 @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
end

def attendance_params(my_params)
 my_params.permit(:present, :employee_id)
end

end
```

**My Model:**

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :employee
 validates :employee_id, uniqueness: { scope: :date }
end
```

**attendances/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag path, form_options do %>
    <h4>Swipe left for absent, right for present!</h4>
      <div class="attendance">
        <% @attendances.each_with_index do |attendance, index| %>
          <%= fields_for 'attendances[]', attendance do |f| %>
            <div class="attendance-card <%= set_background_color(attendance) %>" data-id="<%= attendance.employee.id %>">
              <div class="employee-name">
                <h4><%= attendance.employee.first_name %> <%= attendance.employee.last_name.first %>.</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="attendance-status">
                <% if attendance.present %>
                  <div class="employee-present"><i class="fa fa-check color-green" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <% elsif attendance.present == false %>
                  <div class="employee-absent"><i class="fa fa-times color-red" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <% else %>
                  <% if index == 0 %>
                    <div class="swipe-instructions-left"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left color-red floating-horizontal-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></div>
                    <div class="swipe-instructions-right"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right color-green floating-horizontal-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <%= f.text_field :present, type: 'hidden'%>
              <%= f.text_field :employee_id, type: 'hidden'%>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="sticky-footer">
        <input class='btn edu-button' type="submit" value="Submit" form="attendance">
      </div>
    <% end %>


    <script>
      var swipe_present = function() {
        $('.attendance-card').hammer().bind("swiperight", function(event){
          var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
          $('[data-id=' + id + '] input').first().val('true');
          var $employee = $('[data-id=' + id + '].attendance-card');
          $employee.removeClass("attendance-red");
          $employee.addClass("attendance-green");
          $('[data-id=' + id + '] .attendance-status').html('<div class="employee-present"><i class="fa fa-check color-green" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
          $employee.hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 200, function(){
            $employee.appendTo('.attendance').show();
          });
        });
      };
      var swipe_absent = function(){
        $('.attendance-card').hammer().bind("swipeleft", function(event){
          var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
          $('[data-id=' + id + '] input').first().val('false');
          var $employee = $('[data-id=' + id + '].attendance-card');
          $employee.removeClass("attendance-green");
          $employee.addClass("attendance-red");
          $('[data-id=' + id + '] .attendance-status').html('<div class="employee-absent"><i class="fa fa-times color-red" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
          $employee.hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 200, function(){
            $employee.appendTo('.attendance').show();
          });
        });
      };
      $(document).ready(function(){
        swipe_present();
        swipe_absent();
      });
    </script>
```

**routes**

```
resources :branches do
      resources :employees, only: [ :index, :new, :create ]
      member do
        resources :attendances, only: [ :new, :create ]
        get 'attendance/:date', to: 'attendances#show', as: 'attendance'
        get 'attendance/:date/edit', to: 'attendances#edit', as: 'edit_attendance'
        patch 'attendance/:date', to: 'attendances#update', as: 'update_attendance'
      end
    end
```

**table**

```
create_table "attendances", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.date     "date"
 t.boolean  "present"
 t.boolean  "excused"
 t.integer  "employee_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 t.index ["employee_id", "created_at"], name: "index_attendances_on_employee_id_and_created_at", using: :btree
 t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_attendances_on_employee_id", using: :btree
end
```

I think the problem is in the way I pass the value of boolean **:present** to the DB but if so, anyway I do not know how to make it work.

Thanks for the help!

**Update**

First off all, thanks to @Sebastían, @Gerry and @Pavan for the interest on help me.

Now, how is this working from the console but not from the application?

```
2.3.0 :019 >   Employee.where(branch_id: b).each do |e|
2.3.0 :020 >     new_attendance = Attendance.new(employee_id: e.id, date: Date.today)
2.3.0 :021?>   new_attendance.present = [true, false].sample
2.3.0 :022?>   new_attendance.save
2.3.0 :023?>   end

Employee Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."branch_id" = 3
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Attendance Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."employee_id" = $1 AND "attendances"."date" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["employee_id", 4], ["date", Sat, 08 Jul 2017], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.6ms)  SELECT MAX("attendances"."id") FROM "attendances"
SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "attendances" ("id", "date", "present", "employee_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 35], ["date", Sat, 08 Jul 2017], ["present", true], ["employee_id", 4], ["created_at", 2017-07-08 18:51:01 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-07-08 18:51:01 UTC]]
(5.8ms)  COMMIT
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
Attendance Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."employee_id" = $1 AND "attendances"."date" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["employee_id", 2], ["date", Sat, 08 Jul 2017], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.5ms)  SELECT MAX("attendances"."id") FROM "attendances"
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "attendances" ("id", "date", "present", "employee_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 36], ["date", Sat, 08 Jul 2017], ["present", false], ["employee_id", 2], ["created_at", 2017-07-08 18:51:01 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-07-08 18:51:01 UTC]]
(5.9ms)  COMMIT
```

**Create Action**

```
def create
 params[:attendances].each do |attendance|
  new_attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params(attendance))
  new_attendance.date = Date.today
  new_attendance.save
 end
 redirect_to attendance_branch_path(id: @branch, date: new_attendance.date), notice: 'Attendance taken successfully'
end
```

**Update Action**

```
def update
 params[:attendances].each do |id, params|
  attendance = Attendance.find(id)
  attendance.update(attendance_params(params))
 end
 redirect_to attendance_branch_path(id: @branch, date: params[:date])
end
```

**Params**

```
def attendance_params(my_params)
 my_params.permit(:present, :employee_id)
end
```

And after create those records from console, I´m able to go to application and make updates on those records and works fine.
But if I go to console and delete those 2 last records previously created to make it appear again for mark the attendance in the the application I get the same error:

```
ArgumentError in AttendancesController#create
 wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

 Extracted source (around line #81):

  81: def attendance_params(my_params)
  82:  my_params.permit(:present, :employee_id)
  83: end
```

**I really don´t understand**

Answer (score 2):

`strong_params` doesn't take arguments. You can mark as required a hash that'll go through your params to your controller and there to specify the permitted keys.

So, instead defining `attendance_params` to expect for an argument called `my_params`, then you can just make it a "non-argument" method, and there instead working with `my_params`, then use the `params` instance public method which will return a new `ActionController::Parameters` object, which is initialized with the `request.parameters`.

You could try with:

```
def attendance_params
  params.permit(:present, :employee_id)
end
```

Comment: You forgot to remove `my_params` argument.

Comment: Hi @Sebastían, thanks for your help. I´ve did it that way before ask and throws me the opposite : wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: @Jorge Change this: `attendance.update(attendance_params(params))` to this: `attendance.update(attendance_params)`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry I've dit it but changes nothing. What would be yours best aproach with the create action?

Comment: Ok, that's all for me now. It's 1 am for me, GN.

Comment: @Jorge In create method you need to change this line `new_attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params(attendance))` to   `new_attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params)`

Comment: You need to change all the calls to the `attendance_params` where you're passing an argument, removing it, do it in the `create` and `update` method as @Pavan commented.